# Are the $\alpha_i$ and $\beta$ matrices in Dirac equation unique in the Dirac representation?

Tags: dirac-equation, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

Related question is in [Are the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ matrices of the Dirac equation unique?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/558481/) . However, it does not solve my problem.

My professor asked us to prove that in the Dirac representation, $$\alpha_i=\begin{pmatrix}0 & \sigma_i \\ \sigma_i & 0\end{pmatrix},
\quad \beta=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}.$$

It is obviously for $\beta$. But I could not prove $\alpha_i$.

I started by supposing $ \alpha_i=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf A_i & \mathbf B_i \\ \mathbf C_i & \mathbf D_i\end{pmatrix} $.

From the anti-commutation relation $\{ \mathbf \alpha_i, \beta\}=0$, I can derive $A_i=D_i=0$.

From $\alpha_i^2=1$, I can have $C_i=B_i^{-1}$. Furthermore, from the Hermiticity, I can have $C_i=B_i^{\dagger}$.

But I could not find a way to prove that $C_i=B_i$. The relation $\{ \mathbf \alpha_i, \mathbf \alpha_j \}=0$ for $i\ne j$ does not help.

I have looked in some books and the internet. But these matrices are just given directly without proof.

Now I wonder that whether $\alpha_i$ are unique in the Dirac representation or not.

If they are not unique, maybe I should just prove that $\alpha_i=\begin{pmatrix}0 & \sigma_i \\ \sigma_i & 0\end{pmatrix}$ satisfy all the properties of $\alpha_i$.

Comment: OK. I think they are not unique. We can just let $\alpha_i \rightarrow \alpha_{i+1}$ and we can have another set of $\mathbf \alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I wonder that whether $\alpha_i$ are unique in the Dirac representation or not.

The matrices
$\alpha_i=\begin{pmatrix}0 & \sigma_i \\ \sigma_i & 0\end{pmatrix}$
are certainly not unique, not even in the Dirac representation,
i.e. together with $\beta=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$.

The matrices
$\alpha_i=\begin{pmatrix}0 & U\sigma_iU^\dagger \\ U\sigma_iU^\dagger & 0\end{pmatrix}$,
where $U$ is any unitary $2\times 2$ matrix, are solutions as well.
You can easily prove it by checking their properties (the anti-commutation relations
and hermiticity).

> If they are not unique, maybe I should just prove that
> $\alpha_i=\begin{pmatrix}0 & \sigma_i \\ \sigma_i & 0\end{pmatrix}$
> satisfy all the properties of $\alpha_i$.

Agreed. I would say you are overthinking the given problem.